# Why do Ganesha temples house doves/pigeons?

Tags: temple, ganesha, animals

Many temples in South India dedicated to Ganapati maintain dovecotes. For instance,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35ocltmUtEw

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g304556-d3268808-r151055818-Kaaraneeswarar_Temple-Chennai_Madras_Chennai_District_Tamil_Nadu.html

A simple Google search on 'Ganapati Temple Pigeon' will give many such results. I faintly recall my mother saying something about 'prāsēva' (pigeon seva, literally) at Ganapati temples, but she does not know the details either.

What exactly is the connection? I am looking, in particular, for a reference from scripture.